# Issue while working with django ORM or raw sql query

Tags: python, sql, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

list_edit_drivers.html - this is html file for showing data at front end

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: '_all',
                    defaultContent: ''
                }
            ]
        });
        var table = $('#drivers').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 100,
            "serverSide": true,
            "bSearchable":true,
            "dom": 'blfrtip',
            "ajax": "/fleet/dt/editdrivers/?format=datatables&city_id={{city_id}}",
            "columns": [
                 {
                    "data": "employee_id",
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return '<a href="/fleet/driver/list_drivers/{{city_id}}/view/' + full.id + '">' + full.employee_id + '</a>';
123                     }
                },
                {
                    "data": "uber_name"
                },
                {
                    "data": "mobile"
                },
                {
                    "data": "uber_device_no"
                },
                {
                    "data": "aadhar_no",
                    "bVisible": false,
                },
                {
                    "data": "location.name"
                },
                {
                    "data": "status"
                },
                {
                    "data": "id",
                   
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        
                        return '<a class="btn btn-sm  btn-primary" href="/fleet/driver/list_drivers/{{city_id}}/edit/' + full.id + '">' + 'Edit' + '</a>';
                    }
                }]
        });
    });
```

urls.py - ajax call DriverViewSet url and html render list_edit_drivers url

```
router.register(r'dt/editdrivers', views.DriverViewSet)
path('driver/list_drivers', views.list_edit_drivers, name='list_edit_drivers')
```

views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class DriverViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Driver.objects.filter(is_active=1)
    serializer_class = DriverEditListSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Driver.objects.filter(is_active=1, city_id=self.request.GET.get('city_id'))
        return queryset

@login_required
def list_edit_drivers(request):
    driver = Driver.objects.filter(city_id=request.session['global_city_id'])
    context = {
        'menu_hiring': 'active',
        'submenu_driver_edit_list': 'active',
        'driver': driver,
        'city_id': request.session['global_city_id']
    }
    return render(request, 'hiringprocess/list_edit_drivers.html', context=context)
```

serializers.py

```
class DriverEditListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    city = CitySerializer(read_only=True)
    location = LocationSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = ( 'id','employee_id','employer', 'name','uber_name','uber_device_no', 'mobile', 'location', 'city','shift','status', 'aadhar_no')
```

I need to this sql query implement for change logic. i don't need to change existing field name and all, only change logic based on below sql query. raw query or ORM both okay.

```
    SELECT fleet_driver.id as driver_id, employee_id, uber_name,fleet_driver.city_id, fleet_driver.mobile,uber_device_no, 
fleet_location.name as location_name,
fleet_driver.status as driver_status, fleet_hiring.status as hiring_status
from fleet_driver 
left join fleet_hiring on fleet_driver.id=fleet_hiring.driver_id
left JOIN fleet_location on
fleet_driver.location_id=fleet_location.id
WHERE (fleet_driver.id<4253 )
```

[sql query output ex.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0yN6.png)
models.py

```
class Driver(BaseModel):
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=8,unique=True,null=True, default=True)  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    uber_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True,null=True, blank=True) uber_device_no = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,
    blank=True) 
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,models.CASCADE,verbose_name='City',null=True, blank=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location,models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Location',null=True, blank=True) 
    status = EnumField(choices=['WORKING','ON_LEAVE', 'EXIT', 'REJOINED'], null=True)
 
class Hiring(BaseModel):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('', 'Type...'),
                       ('HR Interview Pass', 'HR Interview Pass'),
                       ('HR Interview Fail', 'HR Interview Fail'),
                       ('Driving Test Pass', 'Driving Test Pass'),
                       ('Driving Test Fail', 'Driving Test Fail'),
                       ('Test Not Interested', 'Test Not Interested'),
                       ('Test Pending', 'Test Pending'),
                       ('Training Completed', 'Training Completed'),
                       ('Training Pending', 'Training Pending'),
                       ('Onboard', 'Onboard'),
                       ('Allocation Completed', 'Allocation Completed')) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 255,choices=STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True) 
    driver = models.OneToOneField(Driver,models.CASCADE,related_name='driver',verbose_name='Driver',null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Can you paste your models as well? It is hard to figure out relations for ORM without models.

Comment: @ raviadhikari updted models.py

Comment: What is that "issue" you're facing? You haven't explained your situation really at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a confusing code in your SQL query you provided.
The id<4253 and id>=4253 refers to all columns, just with an overhead.
I have omitted it.

```py
orm = Driver.objects.filter(
     # because you have written reverse relation in hiring as driver it looks 
     # confusing. You might want to refactor it to hriring
     driver__status__in=(
          'Allocation Completed',
          'Training Completed'
     ).filter(
          # id__lt=4253,
          # id__gt=4253
)
print(orm.query)
```

which spits the following query:

```sql
SELECT "drivers_driver"."id", "drivers_driver"."employee_id",
"drivers_driver"."name", "drivers_driver"."uber_name", 
"drivers_driver"."mobile", "drivers_driver"."uber_device_no" FROM 
"drivers_driver" INNER JOIN "drivers_hiring" ON 
("drivers_driver"."id" = "drivers_hiring"."driver_id") 
WHERE "drivers_hiring"."status" IN (Allocation Completed, Training Completed)
```